# Mails always gets delivered to second MX record

Tags: mx-record

I have setup two MX records for mydomain.tld:

| Name | Type | Pref | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mail | MX | 5 | server1.tld. |
| mailbackup | MX | 10 | server2.tld. |

(Name is just a label, nothing DNS related.) When I try to send test mails from external servers like GMail etc. to user@mydomain.tld they always get delivered to server2.tld. But server1.tld is working correctly, as soon as I disable the mailbackup MX record. Could it be a latency issue of server1.tld? How is a connection being checked from the delivering server's view?

Comment: Does server1.tld show anything in the logs? An attempted delivery?

Comment: What is "Name" in this context, some arbitrary label, or it appears in the DNS?

Comment: To me what you appear to have configured now is MX records for e-mail addressed to `user@mail(.example.com)` and `user@mailback(.example.com)` ; for two different (sub-) domains.   Those are not (necessarily) for the conventional `user@example.com` style addresses. For those   I would expect both your two MX records to either have an empty name, the bare domainname `example.com.` ,  possibly  the bind shorthand `@` or something similar  indicating MX records for a bare domain name, but  not mail & mailbackup.

Comment: In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Comment: Edited the question to reflect the mail domain/subdomains. @Halfgaar: Nothing shows up in the logs of server1.tld.

Comment: @Rob: I wasn't aware that delivery is aware of these subdomains, as it works fine without the failover entry and as my tests go to user@mydomain.tld.

Comment: Please show the actual DNS entries. (They're public anyway.) Without them it's pure guesswork.

Comment: I would never set the priority less 10, I had some headache in the past for this kind, I would suggest that you change the first to 10 which is in most cases the "default" value for buggy software. any the backup to 30 or 40

Comment: From your description you're doing everything right. it's probably going to be impossible to dignose this for sure without you disclosing your domain name... it could be a problem with your DNS provider or your glue records....

Comment: In principle, the delivering server checks DNS and then choses the record with lowest priority numerical value, attempts to deliver there, if it fails to connect or fails with non-permanent code (e.g. *not* a 5xx code), it tries the next to lowest numerically priority record and so on. Either your first server is slow to respond, or some servers choke on values less than 10, or compare them as strings (in which case '5'>'10' so 10 is considered "numerically lower").

Comment: @Nikita Kipriyanov: Thanks, this was the answer I was hoping for.